# Reference pairs of controls

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I have a set of custom user controls, of type "ChartControl".  I want to "pair" these (in some way), such that if having 10 controls, it's 5 pairs of 2 charts. The purpose of this is when I raise some specific event in one chart, I want the Form class to perform an action on both that chart, and it's pair chart, but not the other 8.

So what options do I have on how to "find" this 2nd chart of the pair?  Or in other words: How to organize these charts in a type of list or class structure for this to be easy?

The challenge I see is that when receiving an event from a chart control, I can't simply loop through some list of controls to see where it belongs, as I can't compare the objects:

```
Operator '=' is not defined for types "UserControl"   (VB.NET)
```

Would appreciate some ideas on how to do this. It's probably simple, but my brain seems a bit stuck here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to compare the objects using [Object.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx). You can also group them in any container form and look at its Controls collection. This way you can make the separation GUI instead of program logic.

And: Is the error message you are getting because you are assigning (=) and not comparing (==)? :)

Some pseudocode:

```
private void ChartClicked(object sender, someargs...)
{
   foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
   {
      if (Object.Equals(sender, c)
      {
         // This is the sender
      }
   }
}
```

or

```
private void ChartClicked(object sender, someargs...)
{
   // Was it chart1 that was clicked? (We could use switch statement here to make the code cleaner)
   if (Object.Equals(sender, chart1)
   {
       // Do something to chart5
       chart5.Value = chart1.Value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah.. .Equals(),  hmm I was not aware of this.  No, actually I was typing this in VB.NET, that's why I copy-pasted (=).

Answer (score 2):

Create a new control which comprises of the two charts (and probably other controls as you deem appropriate). That way you can write methods for the control as well that will operate on both of them. It encapsulates the user control pairs to one central element.

Comment: But they are not located "next to eachother", but with other charts in between...